# I can not divide two numbers correctly

Tags: java, android

```
int percent = (score/numberOfQuestions)*100;
progressText.setText(score+"/"+numberOfQuestions+"  "+percent+"%");
```

returns 0% no matter what I tired. I tried casting it to int, double, float

Why does it return 0% for a number like score=5 numberOfQuestions=8?

Comment: you can use 100.0 to cast it to floating point automatically

Comment: Please disregard the advice to use floating point. Sure, it would solve this problem, but you'll get an other set of problems instead and your next question would probably be about how to reduce the number of decimals.

Comment: @Eduardo No, that would be `(5 / 8) * 100.0`, which is `0 * 100.0`, which is `0.0`. The cast to `double` would happen *after* the integer division.

Comment: @harold: it depends if he wants his percentage with decimals or not. Also, rounding will always be downwards.

Comment: @Eduardo rounding can be fixed. And yes there can be valid reason for using floating point anyway, but if you look at his old code he's clearly not expecting any decimals.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that divide two integers gives you the integer part of the result. So,  `(score/numberOfQuestions)` will be always 0.
What you should do is

```
int percent = (score * 100 / numberOfQuestions);
```

Then the `*100` will be executed first, then the divide will give you correct result.

Comment: +1 This is absolutely the best way to handle the operation, using only `int` math.

Comment: One thing that I don't understand: if `score` is an integer, why would multiplying it times 100 turn it into a double?

Comment: @user1301428 it doesn't turn it into a double. It still remains an integer but is a quicker way of finding the percentage of numbers without converting into another form.

Comment: rounding for decimal places will not work if you don't use double.

Answer (score 6):

You need to cast on either of them: -

```
float percent = ((float)score/numberOfQuestions)*100;
```

Since, `5 / 10` is already 0.. Casting the final result to any type will give you 0 only, as in below code: -

```
float percent = ((float)(score/numberOfQuestions))*100;
```

This will also give you `0.0`. Since you are casting `0` to float. Doesn't matter..

Answer (score 3):

Check your integer math. Your code won't work without casting for small values, so just move the operations around:

```
int percent = 100*score/numberOfQuestions;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using an `int` (integer) to store that percentage. Try using `float` or `double` instead making score and number of questions `float` or `double` too (Thanks for teh comments, I totally skipped this...). If you have issues showing the value, I suggest you use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format it.

Rather than using pure `int` math to calculate and store the percentage, I suggest this other alternatives if you want to have decimals in your result.

Comment: You're assuming `score` and `numberOfQuestions` are of type `double`!

Comment: Only using double for `percent` will not solve any problems, as the calculations on the right side operate all on ints -> `(score/numberOfQuestions)` will be 0 if `score<numberOfQuestions`

Comment: Totally right, my apologies. I was assuming what @RichardJPLeGuen said. I've explained the missing bits of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`score/numberOfQuestions` will always provide a number between 0 and 1.  You have two choices depending upon how accurate you need your computation.  For most things, you can change the expression to `(score * 100)/numberOfQUestions`.  This will give you two digits of accuracy.  A problem would occur if `score * 100` overflowed an int.  Given your variable names, I doubt this would happen in this case.  The second possibility would be to convert the expression to double for the computation.

Answer (score 0):

```
int percent=(int)(((double)score/numberOfQuestions)*100);
```